# Switching Settings datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

We are useing the default datepicker for jQuery ( http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ ) but im trying to make a changeable datepicker.

I have a radio button that can be switched between a Delivery and a Pickup. I want costumers to be able to select Satherday when its pickup but unable to select sunday and satherday with Delivery.

I made some code but it doesnt seem to work

**JS**

```
  $('input[name=method]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'pickup') {            
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                    var day = date.getDay();
                                    return [(day != 0), ''];
                                }
                                });
    }

    else {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                                beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
                                });
    }
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<h3>Overige informatie</h3>
<label>Afhalen/Bezorgen</label>
<br>
<div id="project_basket_orderinfoform-method">
   <label><input type="radio" id="project_basket_orderinfoform-method-pickup" name="method" value="pickup"  checked="checked" class=" radio"/>Afhalen</label>
   <label><input type="radio" id="project_basket_orderinfoform-method-deliver" name="method" value="deliver"  class=" radio"/>Bezorgen</label>
   <span class="required-marker">*</span>
</div>

<label for="project_basket_orderinfoform-delivery_date">Aflever-/afhaaldatum</label>
<br>
<input id="project_basket_orderinfoform-delivery_date" type="text" placeholder="" name="delivery_date" value="24-12-2012" class="datepicker datetime"/>
```

So basicly when i switch from Pickup to Delivery and back the datepicker doesnt change its setting `beforeShowDay`. I cant figure out whats going wrong... Im not that quite experienced with datepicker so i wonder did anyone else made this before or can someone see what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you instantiate the datepicker, you cannot change its settings without using the "option" option or you can destroy the datepicker and recreate it.

Comment: Can you give a example with the option?

Comment: `#('selector').datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', 'something')` @Ladineko

Comment: Does that work with more values like show in if ($(this).val() == 'pickup') also?

Comment: $('.datepicker').datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', function(date) { var day = date.getDay(); return [(day != 0), '']; }) WORKS! Cheers lad!

Comment: @Ladineko no problem ^_^ happy to help!